# SSO web and ticket session

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm developping a SSO web system for my company. When poeple want access to an application, it redirects the user on the SSO server (web application) which keeps the authenticated user in memory. The SSO server then redirects the user to the application, which is creating its own session.

The problem is when a user spend a lot of time on the application, the session on the SSO is lost.

Have you an idea to resolve this problem ?

My SSO application is an ASP .NET application and others applications could be in ASP .NET or ASP .NET MVC3.

Thanx for your help

Comment: I had to give this question a -1 because you have not provided any details about what technology you are using, what framework you have built upon, what you have done to research the problem so far, etc. I will be happy to reverse that vote if you provide more relevant details.

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry for that. My SSO application is in ASP .NET and my another application is in ASP .NET MVC. My problem is just that the session on the SSO application is lost. My company refuses to do not declare an infinite timeout for sessions on the SSO application. So i would like know how refresh this session from another application :)

Comment: Well, you can't rely on a session staying around for any length of time, it's just not guaranteed. If your solution depends on that, you may need to find a different solution. An "infinite" timeout should not be required.

Comment: i'm agree with you. Is for that i'm searching to refresh the session on the SSO application. But I have no idea how to do that ...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look into setting the timeout values of the WebAgent by observing the typical usage patterns of your users..

So how do you currently handle the user's SiteMinder session timeout..? Ideally you would be using a redirect URL to a custom page that informs the user that the session was terminated, etc.